# Update a column using current day value for last one year

Tags: plsql

I trying to update two columns using current day value. I need to back track beginning inventory for each day for the last one year. The calculation to calculate beginning inventory is:
*`(Current open inv + Completed inv)-(New receipt) = Beginning inv`* .

The calculated today's beginning inventory will be used as open inv(end inv) for the previous day, and I have completed inv and receipt count for each day.

```
Date   Open_inv   Comp_inv   Receipt   beg_inv
03/20   100        20         30        90
03/19    90        15         20        ?
03/18     ?        25         30        ?
```

Comment: You need to add more details about the columns you are updating and the sql you have tried out till now.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might help

```
SQL> create table t ( d date, o int, c int, r int, b int );

Table created.

SQL> insert into t values ( date '2000-03-20',   100   ,     20   ,      30   ,     90);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values ( date '2000-03-19',    null   ,     15   ,      20   ,     null);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values ( date '2000-03-18',    null   ,     25   ,      30   ,     null);

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> select
  2   d,
  3   case
  4     when row_number() over ( order by d desc ) = 1 then o
  5     else min(o) over () +tot_c-tot_r
  6   end o,
  7   c,
  8   r
  9  from (
 10    select t.*,
 11           nvl(sum(c) over ( order by d desc rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding),c) as tot_c,
 12           nvl(sum(r) over ( order by d desc rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding ),r) as tot_r
 13    from t
 14  );

D                  O          C          R
--------- ---------- ---------- ----------
20-MAR-00        100         20         30
19-MAR-00         90         15         20
18-MAR-00         85         25         30

3 rows selected.
```

Also, if you can phrase your question with the create table and the insert scripts as I've done, it makes it a lot easier for others to help you.